# imploding neighbor elements (by index) in PHP array

Tags: php, foreach, implode

I implode successive words in an array (with respect to the index number) in a loop

```
$array=array(
    1=>array('First','word'),
    5=>array('Second','word'),
    6=>array('Third','word'),
    7=>array('-','non-word'),
    8=>array('Fourth','word'),
    10=>array('Fifth','word')
);

$prev=-1;
$results=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$v){
    $value=$v[0];
    $type=$v[1];
    if($key==$prev+1){ // check if the index is successive
        $results[]=$value; // possibly $results=array('value'=>$value, 'type'=>$type);
    }else{
        echo implode(' ',$results).PHP_EOL; // HERE is the question
        $results=array($value);
    }
    $prev=$key;
}

echo implode(' ',$results).PHP_EOL; // echoing remaining $result
```

My problem is that I do not know how to implement a condition for `non-word` (e.g., hyphen, /, etc).

In the above example, there should be no space around the `$value`, `if($type=='non-word')`.

The intended output is

```
First
Second Third-Fourth
Fifth
```

In general, I want to find a way to incorporate conditions for the type (for example, omitting `non-word` if it is in the beginning or at the end of the group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over each item, and output it, then all that needs doing is:

- check if the next value is successive, if:

  - **no**: add a new line.
  - **yes**: and is a word and current is not a non-word add a space.

```
<?php
$array=array(
    1=>array('First','word'),
    5=>array('Second','word'),
    6=>array('Third','word'),
    7=>array('-','non-word'),
    8=>array('Fourth','word'),
    10=>array('Fifth','word')
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0];
    if (!isset($array[$key+1])) {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    } else if($array[$key+1][1] === 'word' && $array[$key][1] !== 'non-word') {
        echo ' ';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
First
Second Third-Fourth
Fifth
```

https://3v4l.org/IFVa0

Answer (score 1):

I'm just learning regex, but this approach seems to work, though admittedly it's not pretty - mark your non-words in the array so they're easily replaceable with `preg_replace` after the fact

```
$array=array(
    1=>array('First','word'),
    5=>array('Second','word'),
    6=>array('Third','word'),
    7=>array('-','non-word'),
    8=>array('Fourth','word'),
    10=>array('Fifth','word')
);

$prev=-1;
$results=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$v){
    $type=$v[1];
    $value= $type=="non-word" ? "%%".$v[0]."%%" : $v[0];
    if($key==$prev+1){ // check if the index is successive
        $results[]=$value; // possibly $results=array('value'=>$value, 'type'=>$type);
    }else{
        $output = implode(' ',$results); // HERE is the question
        $output = preg_replace("/ %%(.*?)%% /", "$1", $output);
        echo $output.PHP_EOL;
        $results=array($value);
    }
    $prev=$key;
}
```

Here's it in action: https://www.tehplayground.com/wmPSi5wP6eLcBAdk

Comment: I did think of regex to modify the output, but it needs to define all non-words. In your case (defining the word characters), it does not work if a word is made of non-ASCII alphanumeric. In general, it is easier to use `$type` when provided in the loop than guessing that in the output.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by $type, but I did revise my answer to also have an explicit option (search for all `space` `character` `space`)

Comment: In the array, the second column is the type of the value (word or non-word). The problem is that there is a long list of non-word characters. For example, your code does not work for `Testing — Again`

Comment: Sorry @Googlebot - I somehow read the question wrong. I updated my answer, curious if this helps. Cheers

Comment: that's a clever idea!